# sketch effect or cartoon effect to camera in android

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, effect

I saw an app called **Cartoon Camera** .

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fingersoft.cartooncamera

I was wondering how to add effect to camera directly. I know how to add effect after the picture is taken or to a bitmap. But how to do it in real time camera.

I have no idea on how to start this. Please give me some ideas so I can start the project.

Comment: Can somebody answer ??, me too want to know.

Comment: Anyone got answer?

Answer (score 0):

Android OS delivers a built in native filters, their official names are ColorEffects and you an set them easily. The drawback is that you need to implement your own camera in order to use it(Or download android camera from git).

If you just want to use external camera you can find out if the camera broadcast supports color effect.

Then, you can get all the color effects of the camera by doing:

```
mParameters.getSupportedColorEffects();
```

It will return a list of supported color effect, but be aware that also some of the effects are exist in this list - you cannot select them because they are being used as part of a scene so in order to apply them you need also to set the exposure, saturation and more.

The ColorEffects that doesn't based on a scene can be easily apply by the following lines of code:

```
mParameters.setColorEffect(effect);

try {
    mCameraDevice.setParameters(mParameters);
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```